# Number Sense Math

Tags: number-theory

I'm third grade. Shay.
I need help explaining how to get this answer. 
Question: Kyle is thinking of a four digit number in which all the digits are different and ¾ of the digits are odd. What could Kyle number be.

Comment: There  are many possibilities. Are you supposed to produce one?  That should not be hard. All of them? That's a long list. A *count* of how many there are? That seems hard for third grade.

Comment: I'm reading "What could...", which suggests any one will do. This appears to be a task of interpreting what an odd number is, and what $3/4$ means. Sounds about third grade perfect.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a question like this, the first thing to do is find out what the question is asking.

Ask yourself:

1. Do I know what a four-digit number is?  Can I think of an example?
2. Do I know what an odd digit is?  Can I think of an example?
3. Do I know what “All the digits are different” means? Can I think of an example?
4. Do I know what “¾ of the digits” means?
5. Do I know what “¾ of the digits are odd” means?  Can I think of an example?

If you discover that you don't know one of those things, then the next thing to do is to find out what it means.  Nobody can answer a question if they don't understand what the question is asking for!

Then if you still don't know how to solve the problem, try solving a simpler problem.  Maybe you can't find Kyle's number,  but can you find a four-digit number where all the digits are different?  Can you find a number where ¾ of the digits are odd?  Can you find one where ¾ of the digits are odd, and  the digits *aren't* all different?

As you add more conditions, perhaps the problem becomes more difficult, but at the same time you have more practice solving problems of the same kind, and you get better at doing it.  After solving some simpler problems of the same kind, you might be able to solve the original problem when you come back to it.

Comment: This reminds me of a quote by Pólya---"If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier problem you can solve: find it."

Comment: I had that in mind.